# How can I fix Unknown label type: 'continuous'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have 2 column (comment,toxicity) csv file. comment is string and toxicity is float.

| comment | column |
|:---- |:------:|
| toxic comment  | 0,6817   |
I want to do feature importance with this code ;

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import os
import nltk
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import string

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM, Embedding, 
Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional, GlobalMaxPool1D
from tensorflow.keras import initializers, regularizers, constraints, 
optimizers, layers
from tensorflow.keras import layers , activations , models , 
preprocessing, 
utils
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, KeyedVectors
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk import word_tokenize
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

df=pd.read_csv("toxic.csv")
labelencoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['comment'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['toxicity'])

Y=df['toxicity'].values
X=df['comment'].values.reshape(-1, 1)   #target column toxicity


model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(X,Y)
feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_,index=X.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

But I am gettin this error ;

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\hayyi.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 218, in 
> model.fit(X,Y)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble_forest.py",
> line 367, in fit
> y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble_forest.py",
> line 724, in _validate_y_class_weight
> check_classification_targets(y)
>
> File
> "D:\SpyderUI\MiniConda\envs\spyder-env\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py",
> line 198, in check_classification_targets
> raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
>
> ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

How Can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If the problem occurs in the scikit part, then we don't need to see your code to plot the results. We *do* need to see *complete* code to set up the problem - including the necessary `imports`, and initial data for the `df` DataFrame. (It doesn't have to be your real data; it should be small, but it should be sufficient to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question.

Comment: Are all those imports really needed specifically for the code you're showing? Also, showing us that you created the DataFrame by reading a CSV file doesn't help us, because we don't have your file and don't know how it's structured. Instead, you should replace that with hard-coded creation of a DataFrame (i.e. calling the constructor directly).

Comment: I tried so many things to solve that problem because of that it have so many imports. I don't know how to call constructor directly.

Comment: You don't know how to create a DataFrame from hard-coded data in your Python code? Really? Did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it has to be clear what type of problem are you trying to solve. It is a **Classification** or **Regression** problem? (I assume you already know the differences)

In your case, I will assume you are working with a Regression problem because `toxicity` is a  `float`.

In you code, you are using an algorithm that only works for classification problems: `ExtraTreesClassifier()`. The error you receive is because the algorithm don't know how to handle with continuous values in the `y`, it only know how to handle with categorical `y`.

To solve, try moving to another algorithm: `ExtraTreesRegressor()`, which is the same that the one you used but designed to work for Regression problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used ExtraTreesRegressor() but now i am getting 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns' this error.

Comment: Hi! Try to remove `.values` after x and y please.